# Como conseguir sacar por pantalla las coordenadas de un joint o mas por pantalla?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Muy buenas, llevo ya un par de semanas intentando sacar por pantalla las coordenadas por ejemplo de HandLeft(mano izquierda) que visualizo con Kinect dentro de mi aplicación WPF en Visual Studio, pero no se me ocurre la manera de hacerlo.

La parte del código donde creo que debería de ir el código para sacar por pantalla:

```
foreach (Body body in this.bodies)
{
    Pen drawPen = this.bodyColors[penIndex++];

    if (body.IsTracked)
    {
        this.DrawClippedEdges(body, dc);

        IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints = body.Joints;
        // Console.WriteLine("HandRight" + JointType.HandRight);

        // convert the joint points to depth (display) space
        Dictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints = new Dictionary<JointType, Point>();

        // Text = ms_distance_x.ToString("#.##");

        foreach (JointType jointType in joints.Keys)
        {
            // sometimes the depth(Z) of an inferred joint may show as negative
            // clamp down to 0.1f to prevent coordinatemapper from returning (-Infinity, -Infinity)
            CameraSpacePoint position = joints[jointType].Position;
            if (position.Z < 0)
            {
                position.Z = InferredZPositionClamp;
            }

            DepthSpacePoint depthSpacePoint = this.coordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(position);
            jointPoints[jointType] = new Point(depthSpacePoint.X, depthSpacePoint.Y);
        }

        this.DrawBody(joints, jointPoints, dc, drawPen);

        this.DrawHand(body.HandLeftState, jointPoints[JointType.HandLeft], dc);
        this.DrawHand(body.HandRightState, jointPoints[JointType.HandRight], dc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.sensor.DepthFrameReady += this.Sensor_DepthFrameReady;
this.interaction = new InteractionStream(sensor, new InteractionClient());
this.interaction.InteractionFrameReady += interaction_InteractionFrameReady;

...

private void Sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (var frame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            try
            {
                interaction.ProcessDepth(frame.GetRawPixelData(), frame.Timestamp);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
        }
    }
}

private void interaction_InteractionFrameReady(object sender, InteractionFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (var frame = e.OpenInteractionFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            if ((interactionData == null) || 
                (interactionData.Length !== InteractionStream.FrameUserInfoArrayLength))
            {
                interactionData = new UserInfo[InteractionStream.FrameUserInfoArrayLength];
            }
            frame.CopyInteractionDataTo(interactionData);

            foreach (var ui in interactionData)
            {
                foreach (var hp in ui.HandPointers)
                {
                    // Get screen coordinates
                    var screenX = hp.X * DisplayWidth;
                    var screenY = hp.Y * DisplayHeight;

                    // You can also access IsGripped, IsPressed etc.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dado que no controlo mucho de C# no se si te puede servir, espero que si, si no hazmelo saber

Comment: Alberto Martínez, he conseguido otra forma también, puede que mas sencilla y es utilizando un text block en la interfaz y luego en el codigo implementar la función ToString para sacar por pantalla -->>> txtHandLeftX.Text = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX.ToString("HandLeftX : 0.0000");

Comment: @DanielPotrimba puede servir, yo como vengo de android hice lo que pude en la respuesta mirando las docs, si te funciono otro método no dudes en ponerlo como respuesta para que otra gente pueda verlo mejor :D

Comment: la manera en la que lo consigo, desde mi punto de vista se simplifica mucho el código :)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, la forma que he conseguido realizar, desde mi punto de vista, simplifica mucho el código y creo que es una buena solución, el único problema, es que hay que implementar un `TextBlock` en la interfaz para cada coordenadas `X` Y `Z` del `joint` que te interesa, poniendo un nombre específico a cada uno para luego identificarlos y hacer una llamada a esos bloques.La parte de variables globales es una parte de código de mi aplicación, esa parte no es necesaria para sacar por pantalla. Con lo cual la parte del código seria esta:

```
txtHandLeftX.Text = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX.ToString("HandLeftX : 0.0000");
                            txtHandLeftY.Text = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY.ToString("HandLeftY : 0.0000");
                            txtHandLeftZ.Text = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftZ.ToString("HandLeftZ : 0.0000");
```

Comment: Si te ha servido te voto positivo para que la gente lo vea